# How to implement a generic hierarchy of structures with injected functionality

Tags: c#, c++, haskell, d

I want to implement a generic hierarchy for tree structures, which can later be used in an implementation-independent way to describe generic algorithms over trees.

I started with this hierarchy:

```
interface BinaryTree<Node> {
    Node left(Node);
    bool hasLeft(Node);

    Node right(Node);
    bool hasRight(Node);
}

interface BinaryTreeWithRoot<Node> : BinaryTree<Node> {
    Node root();
}

interface BinaryTreeWithParent<Node> : BinaryTree<Node> {
    Node parent(Node);
    bool hasParent(Node);
}
```

Now, basically I want to be able to implement the concept of a subtree in a universal way: 
    For each class T : BinaryTree, I want a 'class' Subtree(T) which provides the same functionality of T (so it must derive from it), and also rewrites the root() functionality.

Something like this:

```
class Subtree<T, Node> : T, BinaryTreeWithRoot<Node> 
    where T : BinaryTree<Node>
{
    T reference;
    Node root;

    void setRoot(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    override Node BinaryTreeWithRoot<Node>::root() {
        return this.root;
    }

    // Now, inherit all the functionality of T, so an instance of this class can be used anywhere where T can.
    forall method(arguments) return reference.method(arguments);
}
```

Now with this code I'm not sure how to create an object of type subtree, since the tree object should in some way be injected.

One approach is to create a subtree class for each tree class i create, but this means code duplication, and, after all, its the same thing.

So, one approach to this is mixins, which allow a generic class to derive from its template parameter.

I'm also interested how such a hierarchy can be implemented in Haskell, since Haskell has a great type system and I think it will be easier to inject such functionality.

For example in Haskell it may be something like:

```
class BinaryTree tree node where
    left :: tree -> node -> node
    right :: tree -> node -> node

class BinaryTreeWithRoot node where
    left :: tree -> node -> node
    right :: tree -> node -> node -- but this is a duplication of the code of BinaryTree
    root :: tree -> node

instance BinaryTree (BinaryTreeWithRoot node) where
    left = left
    right = right

data (BinaryTree tree node) => Subtree tree node = 
 ...

instance BinaryTreeWithRoot (Subtree tree node) where ...
```

I'm interested if and how this can be done in within an oop language (c++,c#,d,java), as c++ and d provide mixins out of the box (and i'm not sure for d), and out of curiosity with the Haskell type system.

Comment: In C# you can not inherit from a generic type parameter. You could implement the `BinaryTreeWithRoot<Node>` interface and chain the `BinaryTree<Node>` calls on to the passed `reference` of `T`

Comment: But this means that for each possible BinaryTreeXXX functionality I should specialize the generic Subtree and chain all the functionality: class Subtree<T, Node> where T : BinaryTree1<Node> ... { all the methods of BinaryTree1 }
class Subtree<T, Node> where T : BinaryTree2<Node> ... { all the methods of BinaryTree2 }
etc...

Comment: true, so `SubTree` should implement `BinaryTreeWithRoot<T>` not `BinaryTreeWithRoot<Node>`

Comment: I don't quite understand how this can be done. If you suggest making the BinaryTreeXXX interfaces more generic, like this: http://pastebin.com/jSdcYYuS
then i can't see how the specific Subtree will map to a specific implementation of the BinaryTree interface. That's because the subtree now has methods, that take a tree as a parameter. 
Also, since C# don't have typedef's, we should explicitly pass all the template type parameters to correctly describe the conditions for them, and this for will become very inconvenient for a class which depends (indirectly) on many template arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach through "BinaryTree"s assumes too much of a fixed structure and unnecessarily defines your interface in a nongeneric way.  Doing this makes it difficult to reuse algorithms as your tree expands into non-binary forms.  Instead, you will need to code your interfaces for multiple styles when such is not necessary or useful.

Also, coding with hasLeft/hasRight checks means every access is a two step process.  Checking existence of a fixed position will not provide for efficient algorithms.  Instead, I think you will find that adding a generic property that may be binary left/right or binary red/black or a character index or anything else will allow much more reuse of your algorithms and checking that data can be done only by those algorithms that need it (specific binary algorithms).

From a semantic view, you want to encode some basic properties first, and then specialise.  When you are "at" a node inside an algorithm, you want to be able to first find the children *edges*.  This should be a container range of edge structures that allow you to navigate to the children nodes.  Since it can be a generic container, it could have 0, 2, 5, 1, or even a 100 edges in it.  Many algorithms do not care.  If it has 0, iterating over the range will do nothing - no need to check hasX or hasY.  For each edge, you should be able to get the node of the child, and recurse for whatever algorithm you wish.

This is basically the approach boost takes in it's Graph library, and it allows for expansion of tree algorithms to graphs where they are applicable, for even better generic algorithm reuse.

So already you have a basic interface with this

```
TreeNode:
  getChildEdges: () -> TreeEdgeRange

TreeEdge:
  getChildNode: () -> TreeNode
```

and whatever range-to-object your favorite language enjoys.  D has a particularly useful range syntax, for instance.

You will want to have some basic Tree object that gives you nodes.  Something like

```
Tree:
  getTreeNodes: () -> TreeNodeRange
```

starts you out.

Now, if you want to support BinaryTrees, do so as a restriction on this interface.  Note that you don't really need any new interface methods, you just need to enforce more invariants - that every TreeNode has 0, 1, or 2 childEdges.  Just make an interface type that indicates this semantic restriction:

```
BinaryTree : Tree
```

And if you want to support rooted trees, adding an interface layer with

```
RootedTree : Tree:
  getRoot: () -> TreeNode
```

adds that capability.

The basic idea is that you shouldn't have to add interface methods to add semantic requirements if you are making your classes more specific down the hierarchy.  Only add interface methods if there is a new semantic behavior that needs accessed.  Otherwise - enforce new invariants on the generic interface.

Eventually, you'll want to decorate nodes and edges with structures that hold data about the node or edge, so you can build Tries and Red-Black trees and all the great tools of advanced algorithmics.  So you will want to have

```
PropertiedTreeNode<Property> : TreeNode:
  getProperty: () -> Property

PropertiedTreeEdge<Property> : TreeEdge:
  getProperty: () -> Property
```

Since this is something you will want to allow generic algorithms to work on, the type information of whether a property is a part of the Tree or not should be generic and something algorithms can ignore.  This puts you on the design track of boost, where these issues have been resolved very elegantly.  I would recommend studying that library if you want ideas on how to build a generic tree algorithm library.

If you follow the above guidelines of types-equating-to-semantic-descriptions, then thee SubTree should be obvious - it's exactly the same type as the tree it is coming from!  In fact, you really should not have a SubTree type at all.  Instead, you should just have a method of the specific TreeNode type you are dealing with

```
PropertiedTreeNode<Property>:
  getSubTree: () -> PropertiedTree<Property>
```

And, as in boost, as you encode more of the information of the capabilities of Tree in it's generic properties, you can get new Tree types with broader interface contracts.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. I think mixing these ::boost concepts with the d programming language will be the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Since D has "real" templates, not generics, making a template class inherit from its template parameter is trivial:

```
class A {}
class B(T) : T {
    static assert(is(B!T : T));  // Passes.
}
```

As far as making `Subtree` work in D, something like this should do it, assuming you also have a template class `Node`:

```
class Subtree(T) : T, BinaryTreeWithRoot!(Node!(T))
{
    T reference;
    Node root;

    void setRoot(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    override Node root() {
        return this.root;
    }
}
```

However, IIUC (correct me if I'm wrong), `T` is the payload of the tree and could therefore be a primitive.  If that's the case, you would be better off getting your ability to use a `Subtree!(T)` as a `T` via [`alias this`](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/class.html#AliasThis), which allows for subtyping without inheritance and works with primitives:

```
class Subtree(T) : BinaryTreeWithRoot!(Node!(T))
{
    T reference;
    alias reference this;  // Make this implicitly convertible to reference.
    Node root;

    void setRoot(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    override Node root() {
        return this.root;
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew D is powerful, but I'm at a basic level of understanding it. I'll check out 'alias this' and the other things. I can live with 'node' being a template class.

Answer (score 5):

Creating a tree interface like this in Haskell is ... unusual.  Both `Node` and `Subtree` are superfluous.  This is partially due to algebraic types, and partially because Haskell data is immutable so different techniques are required to accomplish certain things (like setting the root node).  It is possible to do it, the interface would look something like:

```
class BinaryTree tree where
    left :: tree a -> Maybe (tree a)
    right :: tree a -> Maybe (tree a)

-- BinaryTreeWithRoot inherits the BinaryTree interface
class BinaryTree tree => BinaryTreeWithRoot tree where
    root :: tree a -> tree a
```

Then, with a pretty standard binary tree definition:

```
data Tree a =
  Leaf
  | Branch a (Tree a) (Tree a)

instance BinaryTree Tree where
  left Leaf = Nothing
  left (Branch _ l r) = Just l
  right Leaf = Nothing
  right (Branch _ l r) = Just r

data TreeWithRoot a =
  LeafR (TreeWithRoot a)
  | BranchR a (TreeWithRoot a) (TreeWithRoot a) (TreeWithRoot a)

instance BinaryTree TreeWithRoot where
-- BinaryTree definitions omitted

instance BinaryTreeWithRoot TreeWithRoot where
  root (LeafR rt) = rt
  root (BranchR _ rt l r) = rt
```

Since this interface returns a `Maybe (tree a)`, you can also use `left` and `right` to check if the branches exist instead of using separate methods.

There's nothing particularly wrong with it, but I don't believe I've ever seen anyone actually implement this approach.  The more usual techniques are either to define traversals in terms of `Foldable` and `Traversable` or create a [zipper](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Zippers).  Zippers are simple to derive manually, but there are several generic zipper implementations, such as [zipper](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zipper), [pez](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pez), and [syz](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syz).

Comment: I like this approach. It is simpler, because it eliminates the Node and the Subtree. I'll give it a look to the zipper and multirec packages, because this may be exactly what I need (for a Haskell implementation).
I'm asking the question because i want to describe various algorithms over trees independent of the tree structures and i'm not sure how to make them as general as possible.

Comment: For example, let's say I want the following "capability" (build a segmented tree): Given an shape-immutable tree T with nodes that contain elements of a Monoid.  Let L be the set of leaves and let this set be well-ordered (so on the leaves I have a static(doesn't change its size) sequence of monoid elements. Want to support the following queries:  get::leaf a -> leaf b -> monoid, which gets the accumulated value of mapply over the range [a,b], and change :: tree -> leaf -> monoid -> tree, which changes the value at a leaf.

Comment: This functionality is pretty simple to implement and requires a binary tree with a notion of parent to be available. I want to be able to describe the algorithm independent of the specific tree realization, and these classes that I proposed are to 'plug-in' a generic tree, which can be implemented in various ways (for example: the tree may be represented by a list, and the left and right functions will take position p in the list and return 2*p and 2*p+1, which is perfectly reasonable tree.

Comment: It does sound like a zipper is what you're looking for in Haskell-land.  More to the point, a zipper implements a generic traversal over any container data type, not just a tree.  This type class approach should work too, except as Landei points out you need to be careful with parent links as they'll create cyclic data structures.

Comment: I can see why I'll get a cyclic data structure. The simplest solution I can think of is for the leaf to represent not a node, but a sequence of moves, leading to the leaf, plus the data inside it (for a constant-time data lookup).

Comment: @comco - that could take a lot of space, and if the shape of the tree ever changed racalculating everything would be a significant amount of work.  For a special-purpose tree implementation that might be ok, but I'm skeptical it would work well in general.

Comment: I agree. But in some cases there may be less data to encode a position in a tree. For example, for a binary search tree with data only on its leaves, each leaf will have a key which is an element from a well-ordered set, and all the internal nodes will contain information for the minimal and maximal key in that given subtree. In this key, each leaf is uniquely determined by its key and this means less data.

Comment: But here the thing is that the concept 'give me the parent' actually makes no sense for pure functional languages, its unnatural, and as such, it shouldn't be used at all. This leads me to a conclusion that there might be some very deep obstacles in describing various algorithms on trees on different programming paradigms. Because the 'parent' concept is so simple and natural in an imperative paradigm.
I think zippers will do the work.

Answer (score 2):

In C# 4 I would use dynamics for achieving this goal. For example you could try defining the SubtTree class as:

```
public class Subtree<T, Node> : DynamicObject, BinaryTreeWithRoot<Node> where T : BinaryTree<Node>
{
    private readonly T tree;

    public Subtree(T tree)
    {
        this.tree = tree;
    }
}
```

and override appropriate methods of DynamicObject using methods/properties of tree. More information (and sample code) can be found in this great blog post about [Using C# 4.0 dynamic to drastically simplify your private reflection code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2010/01/18/use-c-4-0-dynamic-to-drastically-simplify-your-private-reflection-code.aspx).

It is worth mentioning that due to usage of dynamic capabilities and reflection, small performance overhead will be introduced as well as reduced safety (as it may involve violation of encapsulation).

Comment: Good point, and good link. But it is good to point out that you will pay a (small) price in terms of safety and performance.

Comment: @dema80: thanks for the input, I've modified my answer as suggested

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, one approach is to create a subtree class for each tree class i create,
This means code duplication, but it can be somehow "avoided", or better, automated, using reflection and T4. I did it myself for a past project and it works quite well!

You may start from Oleg Synch blog for an overview on T4. Here a good example of automatically generated classes: http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-decorator-classes/

Comment: OK. I guess in C# the best approach will be something like this (Reflection) or using Expressions. How about in the other languages?
The bad thing is that using reflection cannot be strictly checked during compile - time.
Ultimately i'd like a strict compile-time alternative (the drawback of c++ is that there the generics are not checked and you can't put conditions on them, which in the real life means strange errors and bad, bad error messages.)

Comment: You can indeed write template <class T, class Node> class Subtree : public T ... in C++, but not in C# (as you pointed out correctly). 
I use it for "automatic singletons", like the one you may find here http://scottbilas.com/publications/gem-singleton/

Answer (score 0):

You could do:-

```
public class Node {
    public Node Left {get; set:}
    public Node Right {get; set;}
    public Node Parent {get; set;}  // if you want to be able to go up the tree
    public Node Root {get; set;}    // only if you want a direct link to root
}
```

A sub-tree is just a tree, and every tree can be represented as the root node of that tree and then that node can have properties enabling navigation through the tree.

Make this a generic `Node<T>` and store the value too.  If you don't like public setters make them private and set them only in a constructor or some safe `AddLeft(...)`, etc. methods.

You can get rid of `Root` too and just traverse up the `Parent` links until you find a null `Parent` value (or reach the top node for your subtree case).

Comment: I can see 2 problems with this approach:
1. In this Node class we assume that we have access to the parent node and the tree has a root. But for example if the tree node is defined as this:

 struct node {
  node* left, *right;
 };

now, being at a particular node, we do not have the information to og upwards. Another thing is that some alogrithms do not 'require' a tree node to have access to a parent to work. That's why I want to implement them over a BinaryTree, not a BinaryTreeWithRoot.

Comment: The other thing is that sometimes the node information itself will not be enough to 'tag' a place in a tree without the tree itself.

For exapmle, I want to allow a compressed tree (that is an array, indexed from 1 with length n, where the 'node' is just an index, and a left(node) operation is (0 + 2*node) and right(node) is (1 + 2*node). That is, putting all that local information on a node is not good for every occasion.

Comment: The pointer to parent would cause problems in pure languages, e.g. in Haskell. Yes, you can beat cyclic dependencies somehow into submission (thanks to lazyness), but it gets really ugly.

Comment: @Landei: very true.  It's a simple knot to tie, but then things like `Eq` get nasty.  Zippers are much easier to work with.